# MySQL performance issue on a simple join with big tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I'm migrating a PHP application from MSSQL Server to MySQL and I'm stuck with a simple query that with MSSQL Server lasts 0,5 seconds and with MySQL 50 seconds. Any ideas? Indexes? Server configuration? The MySQL server hardware is equal or better than the MSSQL server.

**Table structure**

Both are InnoDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nec` INT(11),
    `start_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `end_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `IX_nec` (`nec`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tb2` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nec` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `end_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `IX_nec` (`nec`)
);
```

The tables are *big*. Tb1 has around 300.000 rows and tb2 around 400.000.

**Select**

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM tb2
LEFT JOIN tb1 ON tb1.nec = tb2.nec
```

The result is around 180.000.000.

This is only a sample, the final goal is a bigger query with other date filters/intersections and more.

**Explain plan**
[image: Explain Plan]
[image: Query on MySQL]

Execution plan from SQL Server:
[image: Execution plan from SQL Server]
[image: Query on SQL Server]

**Configuration, hardware, ...**
@@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 2147483648
SELECT version(): 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
[Profiling of the query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbkqqy4zruu43tm/profiling.csv?dl=0) (CSV file)
[Procedure Analyse()](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hl6hm7cwjllnxw/analysis.xls?dl=0) (XLS File)
[my.cnf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wuznstnn45pp11i/my.cnf?dl=0)
System:
 VMware Virtual Platform
 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530  @ 2.40GHz
 4GiB DIMM DRAM EDO
 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Linux gt 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64)

Comment: Condolences. I understand wanting to get a cheaper or open DB, but these days that's Postgresql, not MySql. MySql hasn't kept pace since 2004 with advances made in Sql Server, Oracle, and Postgresql.  It's not really even a modern DB engine any more: no CTEs (recursive or otherwise), no windowing functions, no lateral joins/apply, no full join, and much more.

Comment: It might be a memory issue edit your question with `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` and also  add the explain plan

Comment: I'll bet it will be much faster if you use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. Do you need to count rows in `tb2` that don't have any match in `tb1`?

Comment: Well... it's not the default 128MB, but 2GB still seems very small for a real database server. Ideally, you want enough there to keep all of your tables and indexes in memory all the time (though it's common enough not to be able to do this). By comparison, the Sql Server I'm working with right now has more than 16GB in it's buffer pool equivalent, and this is still small by modern standards.

Comment: @Mihai posted @@innodb_buffer_pool_size and explain plan

Comment: THe issue is I think the CROSS join,it has to match multiple rows in one table with multiple rows in the other.I have no idea how you can speed that up

Comment: I was afraid of a conclusion like this @Mihai :-( I don't understand such a big difference between the two db engines.

Comment: Can you get the query plan from SQL Server?  It sounds like it has some special trick for that unlikely query.

Comment: The buffer_pool_size is not an issue.  This is running in the two indexes, each of which is 10-20MB.

Comment: "This is only a sample" - Well... adding a `WHERE` clause leads to lots of changes in the query plan.  Ditto for adding columns.

Comment: @RickJames added the execution plan from sql server. Is a sample, but it's the actual query that executed on MySQL takes 50s and in SQL Server 0,5s. But it's only the base of a more filtered query (with the same performance issue).

Comment: @Dimas - I don't know how to read SQL Server's execution plan, but I guess it was using multiple cores, which MySQL does not do.  Still, that would explain only part of the 100x difference.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the Answer**

I have create 2 sample table with random data (i know its not the same) and 500000 rows each and test your query. It will take 1,1 sec. So i will nearly sure that is a configuration or Hardware Problem. So i will use some more Information. Can you me post the Output of the querys please

1) SELECT VERSION();

2) The output of this

```
SET PROFILING=ON;

SELECT count(1)
FROM tb2
LEFT JOIN tb1 USING(nec);

SHOW PROFILE ALL;
SET PROFILING=OFF;
```

3) your my.cnf

4) Some infos about the Hardware and operating system

and you can check also this query. it takes only 500 ms on my Server

```
SELECT sum(IF(s IS NULL,1,s)) AS cnt
FROM tb2
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT nec, SUM(1) AS s FROM tb1 GROUP BY nec) tmp USING (nec) ;
```

Comment: I added all the information on the first post. I tried your last query and it takes only 800ms!!! Why???

Comment: Why not :-) , its better than 50 sec. I will answer later, i now out to visit someone. When i am back i will read your post, sorry for the delay

Comment: A big mistake on my part: on tb1 the 'nec' field can be null. In fact there are many rows with 'nec' = NULL. In fact, the original query/SELECT try to discard NULLs adding condition tb1.nec IS NOT NULL, but this doesn't help.

Comment: i also forgot one query to execute **SELECT *
FROM tb2
LEFT JOIN tb1 ON tb1.nec = tb2.nec 
PROCEDURE ANALYSE();** can you please also execute this for me. thx

Comment: Added analyse, but select * is a never ending, I executed it only for id and nec fields.

Comment: Have you had a while to look at it? Sorry, I'm a little desperate

Comment: @Dimas - yes i have seen many things in the my.cnf. Is it possible that we phone this evening. I am at home from 18:15. After this we can write the Answers here

Comment: Sorry! Mail sent

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that could be going on here, but given you're in the process of moving from one DB type to another, it's likely a *new* server. With that in mind, there could just be some basic server tuning that still needs to happen. For example, MySql's buffer pool must be set manually, or it won't use much of the memory in the server. Has this been done?

Comment: please post us the EXPLAIN of your statement, but it look everything ok. Which engine you using you.

Comment: @BerndBuffen explain posted. The engine is InnoDB.

Comment: is it possible that the explain is from **SELECT count(1)
FROM tb1 a
LEFT JOIN tb2 b ON b.nec = a.nec** where the table names are changed

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes, sorry!! Updated explain plain (I'm trying mixing the SQL -with no luck- and copied the bad explain)